# Bug CleverBeagle Pup 2.0 Meteor GraphQL deployment on Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, websocket, graphql

**1) In the first time,** when I deployed the origin code to heroku server with git clone https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup

The launching application didn't work.

I managed to correct this with to copy the content of 'settings-development.json' file and paste in Heroku => myProject => Setttings => Reveal Config Vars => Key : METEOR_SETTINGS and Value : I pasted here the content.

thanks to :
- https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup/issues/9
- https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup/issues/197

So, now, the app is showing on server.

**2) On Chrome console, I have this error :**

> `50d72c91808ef7fba57f920b67d152d2d57698eb.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4001/graphql' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

so I changed this in METEOR_SETTINGS

```
"graphQL": {
      "httpUri": "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
      "wsUri": "ws://localhost:4001/graphql"
    },

to

"graphQL": {
      "httpUri": "https://myproject.herokuapp.com:3000/graphql",
      "wsUri": "wss://myproject.herokuapp.com:4001/graphql"
    },

Note without https and wss, the app is not showing
```

**3) Now on Chrome Console, I have :**

this warning :

> 50d72c91808ef7fba57f920b67d152d2d57698eb.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myproject.herokuapp.com:4001/graphql' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

and after several warning above, I have this error :

> 50d72c91808ef7fba57f920b67d152d2d57698eb.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myproject.herokuapp.com:4001/graphql' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

**By using the origin source code from Pup, I can signup on server but I cannot create a new document.**

**Any help, please ?**

Thank you

---

**EDIT 15 JAN 2019**

**4) I remove Port like this : **

```
"httpUri": "https://myproject.herokuapp.com/graphql",
"wsUri": "wss://myproject.herokuapp.com/graphql"
```

Now, I can create New document on https://myproject.herokuapp.com/documents

but I still have this warning :

> fe6fa1ac83e19aa2513ac3f97293600e8dc99e8e.js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
>   WebSocket connection to 'wss://myproject.herokuapp.com/graphql'
>   failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

and this error :

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myproject.herokuapp.com/graphql'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   503

**any idea ?**

**Thanks**

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Check here : https://spectrum.chat/cleverbeagle/pup/bug-deployment-on-heroku~ab612c22-9c93-441d-aee6-74507dbb734e